# How to resolve a build/pipeline issue of Visual studio 2019 .NET core project via .yml file in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, visual-studio-2019

```
   (CoreCompile target) -> 
     C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\2zKvRX8Z\3\bitrode_software\sourcecode\LCN2\LCN2_Related\LookupTableApp\LookupTableApp\CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators\CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.IMessengerRegisterAllGenerator\__IMessengerExtensions.g.cs(13,6): error CS0592: Attribute 'global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.DynamicallyAccessedMembersAttribute' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'method, property, indexer, field, parameter, return, type parameter' declarations. [C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\2zKvRX8Z\3\bitrode_software\sourcecode\LCN2\LCN2_Related\LookupTableApp\LookupTableApp\LookupTableApp_qj1rd0mm_wpftmp.csproj]
```

1. Checked for Outdated Dependencies and updated the CommunityToolkit.MVVM to ver 8.2.2
2. Added -restore in .yml file to restore the nuget packages

- 'msbuild -restore LCN2\LCN2_Related\LookupTableApp\LookupTableApp.sln /p:Configuration="Release" -m'

How to add Analyzers for CommunityToolkit.MVVM in VS2019 .Net core application? Suspect this could be the root cause of this issue.